# Angular datetimepicker binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm working on a projects with Angular4 and TypeScript. I encountered a problem which could not solve.

So my problem is I'm taking 4 dates in a form as a user input but I can not bind them so here is my typescript:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var $1: any;
declare var $2: any;
declare var $3: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-leave-form',
  templateUrl: './leave-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leave-form.component.css']
})
export class LeaveFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private leaveFormService:LeaveFormService) { }

  leaveForm:LeaveForm=new LeaveForm();

  ngOnInit() {

  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
  $1('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  });
  $2('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
  $3('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
}
```

And here is the html, html is to long so I just write two datepicker part. some property like `name, city` etc. are binded and when user submit the value of every things OK, but dates are undefined.

```
<form>
  <table>  
    <td> <label>leave date</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
          <div class="date-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="leaveForm.endDateOfLeave" name="endDayOfLeave" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <label>return date</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
          <div class="date-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker4'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="leaveForm.returnDate" name="returndate" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button (click)="addLeaveForm()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Gönder</button>
</form>
```

To sum up I think problem is in the typescript code but I could not solve it, look for older post but none of them worked and some of them too complicated. I have tried:

```
$1('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  onSelect:(e)=>{
    this.leaveForm.endDateOfLeave=e;
  }
});
```

But it fires error: `option onSelect is not recognized!`

So what is the problem?

Comment: Have you merging Jquery in typescript?\

Comment: what does $2(), $3() do?

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury $(), $1(),$2(), $3(), datepicker function for four datepicker input. RameshRajendran do you have better solution?